# Trying to recover signal in AM modulation

Tags: amplitude-modulation

[image]

The circuit above is the AM transmitter and the other circuit is the AM receiver. The AM transmitter consists of: Baseband signal (source), BB amplifier and adder (MixerIn), mixer (it's a pulse/square wave with 100kHz frequency, 50% duty cycle - MixerOut), band pass filter (center frequency 100kHz and BW around 4kHz, adapted to 50ohms in and out) followed by a power amplifier.

The receiver consists of another amplifier, a pulse (same frequency as the BB/source signal) and a low pass filter with cut frequency 1kHz.

Image below shows the source signal and the modulated signal after exiting the band pass filter. I would say everything is ok here.

[image]

Here's the FFT of those signals:

[image]

I noticed that the gain in frequencies 99kHz,100Khz and 101Khz is pretty low, not sure if this causes any troubles.

[image]

Here's the signal after leaving the power amplifier (vout) and the signals that go in the receiver:

[image]

Their FTT:

[image]

The demodulated signal (Vout2) has -20dB at 1kHz i think this might be a problem... also there's another frequency at 2kHz with similar gain even though it passed through out a low pass filter.

[image]

[image]

So here's the final result:

[image]

[image]

I tried to put a low pass filter that has a lower cut frequency and nothing good happened (it had -7db at 2kHz, that's the max i can without also affecting the 1kHz frequency using [this filter calculator](https://leleivre.com/rf_butterworth_LPF.html))

Comment: Why is the demodulator (V5) running at 1kHz? I'd want 100 kHz - at the carrier frequency. You might try it with various delays (between 0 - 10us) too. With V5 running at 100kHz, you'd be simulating a *direct-conversion receiver*, also called *zero-I.F. receiver*.

Comment: @glen_geek Yes, that was the issue. Now everything runs fine